# cannot install apn in php for ios push notifications on ubuntu

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cakephp-model

I am trying to run the command

```
sudo pecl install apn
```

But unable to install the apn please see http://libcapn.org/php-apn/

I am on ubuntu 14.4.

It gives following error

```
downloading apn-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download apn-1.0.3.tgz (14,406 bytes)
.....done: 14,406 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
libcapn installation prefix [no] : yes
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootkK8px0/apn-1.0.3
running: /tmp/pear/temp/apn/configure --with-apn
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -      I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -    I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for apn support... yes, shared
checking for PHP 5.3.0 or greater... 50509
checking for apn.h in default path... not found
configure: error: libcapn is not found. Please visit to http://www.libcapn.org/php-apn  for more information
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/apn/configure --with-apn' failed
```

I am not sure where to ask this question, so I am just asking here.

Thanks in advance.

Please tell if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed following this steps.

You need to install [libcapn](http://libcapn.org/). Here you are the [installation steps](http://libcapn.org/doc/html/install.html).

To install libcapn one of the requirements is CMake >= 2.8 then you have to install it first if you don't have it: `apt-get install cmake.`

By default libcapn is installed on `/usr/local`. I recommend don't change the installation path and when the apn installation prompt "libcapn installation prefix [no] : " you have to put this path.

Don't forget that you should add "extension=apn.so" to php.ini